# Make Wubi installation quicker

Tags: wubi

Wubi installation needs to download ubuntu-12.04-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, and this process is extremely slow. I can download this file from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ faster.

How can I use a installer disk I downloaded myself in the installation?

Comment: you can place the downloaded ISO file in same directory where wubi.exe is

Comment: Yes download the ISO, put wubi.exe and Ubuntu-XXXXXX.xxx.ISO in a same folder and then run Wubi. Wubi will automatically detect the ISO and start the installation.

To be sure, you can turn off the internet ;)

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus